# Why does my React Router return blank pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I am using the latest  version of create-react-app. I have searched all tutorials and tried a few websites with different tutorials but I am not getting errors.

I am trying to return the pages within my app. I have done both functional components and class based components but no look. I have tried wrapping in return but it won't render. All the app works but the pages content do not display :(

About.js and Home.js are the same like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
);

export default About;
```

Nav.js is simple enough:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import './css/Nav.css';

const Nav = () => (
    <ul>
        <li>
            <NavLink
                activeClassName="active"
                to="/">Home</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
            <NavLink
                activeClassName="active"
                to="/about">Admin</NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
);

export default Nav;
```

And finally the index.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import {
      BrowserRouter as Router,
      Route,
      Switch
    } from "react-router-dom";
    import registerServiceWorker from './misc';

    // COMPONENTS
    import Nav from './nav/Nav';

    // PAGE COMPONENTS
    import Home from './pages/Home';
    import About from './pages/About';
    import Page404 from './pages/404';

    // CSS
    import './css/Index.css';

    // CONSTRUCT
    class SmartApartmentApp extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Router>
            <div className="App">
                <Nav />
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" Component={Home} />
                  <Route path="/about" Component={About} />
                  <Route component={Page404} />
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
            </div>
          </Router>
        );
      }
    }

    // EXECUTE
    export default SmartApartmentApp;
    ReactDOM.render(<SmartApartmentApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
    registerServiceWorker()

;
```

Comment: I think that you need to add the exact prop to your home route like so :
`<Route exact path="/" Component={Home} />`

Comment: use component instead of Component

Comment: @IgorStecyura thank you so much. Please create an answer so I can mark it correct ;)

Comment: @TheBlackBenKid created:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **component** property instead of **Component**.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is for using wrong prop name `Component`!

To resolve this issue in the Route component pass `component` prop using lowercase `c` instead of `Component` using uppercase `C`.

**Example:**

```
<Route path="/about" component={About} />
```